# Python - Compare two times to create a dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I have a column on a dataframe and I want to compare to a variable if the time is higher than I want to create another column with value 'Good' else 'Bad'.
For that I am using the following code:

```
time = '00:00:00'
time  = dt.datetime.strptime(time,'%H:%M:%S').time
df['value'] = np.where(df['time_df'] >= time, 'Bad', 'Good')
```

However, when I run my code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you missed the `()` at the end of your second line: `time  = dt.datetime.strptime(time,'%H:%M:%S').time()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
time  = dt.datetime.strptime(time,'%H:%M:%S').time
```

To:

```
time  = dt.datetime.strptime(time,'%H:%M:%S').time()
```

Then it should work.